# CircularProgress and LinearProgress multi-color

Tags: material-ui

Using CircularProgress and LinearProgress is it possible to configure multiple colors to be used for charting purposes?  For example being able to represent different percentages of 100% in different colors.

No documentation or online articles found for doing so however I could have missed it.

(According to mui support guidelines, asking here to confirm prior to submitting a feature request)